# Non-unique foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, key

Do foreign keys have to be unique?

I'm trying to create a table that stores the foreign key that references to a user and a column 'profileIconId'. The purpose of the table is to have a list of icons that the user owns. I would like to use cascade delete.

My other choice is to use `SELECT FROM WHERE` to retrieve the list and use `DELETE FROM WHERE` to delete all rows that matches the key when the user is removed.

Answer (score 7):

No, they don't. In fact, one of the most common uses of a foreign key is a one-to-many relationship, such as between *Customers* and *Orders*, for example.

Answer (score 4):

No, Foreign Key in a table doesn't have to be unique in said table.

BUT, as it is the Primary Key of another table, it must be unique in this table.

Comment: Which DBMS this BUT applies? I checked MariaDB, it can create non-unique FK referencing primary key. Why must be that unique?

Comment: @midenok Let's say you have `table_A` containing a field `table_B_id` (FK to `id` of `table_B`): `table_B_id` doesn't have to be unique as it is a FK in `table_A`, BUT `id` of `table_B` has to be unique as it is a PK

Comment: That's different keys. You confuse foreign key with referenced key. No, in referenced table referenced key can be non-unique too.

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

But the values must exists first on the parent table before you can insert it on the table.

Answer (score 3):

No, foreign keys do not have to be unique.  Indeed, a lack of uniqueness is requisite for one-to-many or many-to-many relations.

Answer (score 0):

**Foreign key**(s) must reference a unique set of attributes in the referenced table. So, your foreign keys: *user* and *profileIconId* don't need to be unique, but what they reference does.

Consider the following schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  ... omitted ...
);

CREATE TABLE icons (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  ... omitted ...
);

CREATE TABLE user_icons (
  user INTEGER REFERENCES users,
  profileIconId INTEGER REFERENCES icons
);
```

The `user` and `profileIconId` values do not need to be unique in the `user_icons` table, but `id` in `users` and `icons` must be unique (or technically a **candidate** primary **key**).

Note, the referenced columns in this case must be unique to qualify as Primary Keys.

This would be an acceptable way to accomplish the goal of creating a table that fulfills the *user has zero or many icons* relationship.